# Restrictions on shri rudram or other vedic stutis

Tags: vedas

Shri Rudram or RudraPrashna is a part of yajurveda it is generally recited during abhishek/consecration of Lord Shiva or even just to worship him it is stuti of Lord Rudra.

My question is if Rudraprashna is part of yajurveda and it is also recited during Shravan even on restricted tithis, so is it okay because Manu Smriti restricts it.

**Restricted tithis**:

Restricted tithis are the days when one cannot recite or study vedas.
The days are

1) Ashtami: Eighth day from every full-moon/no-moon day

2)Poornima/Purnami: Fullmoon day

3) Krishna Paksha Chaturdashi: one day before no-moon day

4) Amavasya: No-moon day.

Also there are some more restrictions defined, but do they apply to shri Rudram or any other vedic stutis(which are derived from vedas).
other Vedic Stutis are Ganpati Atharavashirsha, Purusha Suktam, Bramhanaspati Suktam,Shri Suktam etc.

Comment: It certainly doesn't apply to the Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad, because those restrictions are about the chanting of mantras from the Samhitas of the Vedas; they don't apply to reciting Upanishads.  But yeah, I think those restrictions would most definitely apply to the Rudram and the other Vedic hymns you mentioned.  I'm not sure if chanting the Rudram during Shravana has a basis in Hindu scripture, although I think worshipping Shiva during Shravana does have a basis.

Comment: On a side note, like I told you before the chanting of the Brahmanaspati Sukta is based on a misconception, because it's actually a hymn to Brihaspati and not Ganesha.

Comment: Yeah actually that's exactly what I think!, and by the way some people regularly recite shri rudram during shravan for abhishek of lord shiva, and it should be regularly done without hindrance throughout shravan month.

Answer (score 2):

There is a time period which is called `ana-adhyanayana period` in which vedas are not taught or practiced and the students and gurus will indulge themselves in practicing other saatvic activities.

During these time period of a year, in present times, other chant-able texts are adopted. This practice varies from group to group. What can be chanted and what not also varies.

As an exception, when performing brahmayagyam, one has to chant a prashnam of one's shaaka. This has to be done on daily basis even during this period and that includes all the part of vedas the question covers.

Comment: I am asking about practices like shravan where we should chant it daily for shiva abhishek.

Comment: May be I haven't conveyed it clearly. The most rigorous practitioners will not chant any part of veda during these non-observance period.

Comment: What is the precedent or thought process behind this ana-adhyanayana period? Why are these tithis restricted? Is the objective merely giving a rest to the body and brain every 8 days?